# How do I refer the key value in for_each of terraform to get the attribute reference?

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform0.12+

I am trying to write a few checks to the helm_release resource. I want to use for_each to check the status of helm releases in the cluster. To start with I have a setup as below to deploy the current charts. I have a locals section where I mention the chart name and version

```
locals {
  chart_versions = {
    redis       = "6.0.1"
    nginx       = "1.2.1"
    vault       = "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Then I refer to the chart version in the helm_release as below

```
resource "helm_release" "redis" {
  name  = "redis"
  chart = "bitnami/redis"
  version = local.chart_versions.redis
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx" {
  name  = "nginx"
  chart = "nginx"
  version = local.chart_versions.nginx
}

resource "helm_release" "vault" {
  name  = "vault"
  chart = "valult"
  version = local.chart_versions.vault
}
```

Observe that my resource name always matches with the chart names in locals. Now I am trying to loop over the locals and try to fetch the release status

```
resource "null_resource" "helm_release_status" {
 
  for_each = local.chart_versions
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      echo 'The name of the chart ${each.key} has been ${helm_release.${each.key}.status}' >> Infra-Smoke-Tests.txt 
    EOF
  }
  depends_on = [
    helm_release.${each.key}
  ]
}
```

Since I named all my helm_resources with the key values from the locals, I wanted to get something like this.

```
The name of the chart ${each.key} -->(redis) has been ${helm_release.${each.key}.status}
```

--> should get the status of the redis release and the loop has to parse all the charts.

I am able to get the chart values with ${each.key} but I am not able to use this to get the status attribute of the helm_release. Does terraform support this? I tried the join function to concatenate the strings but was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to use this to get the status attribute of the helm_releas

There reason is that something like `${helm_release.${each.key}.status}` is **not supported** in TF. You have to re-architect your TF so that you never have to do such a thing.

The easiest would be through `for_each`:

```
locals {
 releases = {
    redis = {
       chart = "bitnami/redis"
       version = local.chart_versions.redis
    },
    nginx = {
       chart = "nginx"
       version = local.chart_versions.nginx
    },
    vault = {
       chart = "valult"
       version = local.chart_versions.vault
    }
  }
}


resource "helm_release" "release" {
  for_each = local.releases
  name  = each.key
  chart = each.key.chart
  version = each.key.version
}

 provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      echo 'The name of the chart ${each.key} has been ${helm_release.release[each.key].status}' >> Infra-Smoke-Tests.txt 
    EOF
  }
```